# Combine Actionscript/Flex Air Android Project with Java Android Project

Tags: java, android, actionscript, air, integration

**Background:**
I have a Air Android project written in ActionScript using Flash Builder, and a Android Project in Java using Eclipse. I want to combine these two project, which I want to integrate the Air project into my Java Android project. I don't want to have two standalone projects.

My Air project use **Adobe Media Server** and **rtmp** protocol to publish/play live streams.

**Several Approaches I have tried:**

1. **Adobe Native Extention**: I can call Java native code from my Air project but this is the opposite of what I want to do.
2. **Java Native Interface**: I can use it to call c/c++/assembly... but I didn't see how JNI calls Air project
3. **Android Webview**: Created a html file embed the .swf file of my Air project, and using Android Java Webview to run the .swf file directly. But it is not working anymore and I guess is Android is not supporting flash player anymore after 2011.

**Question:**

1. I'm wondering if what I want to do is possible. If so, could anyone give me some directions?
2. I can package my Air Android project to .apk. But I didn't find a way to use a existing .apk from another android project.
3. Do I have to use cross-compiler to make my Air project into .jar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you've rightly identified an ANE is the opposite of what you want, you can provoke your AIR from Java and thats about all you can do. In short you can not integrate a compiled AIR into a Java app.
2. [Even in Java you can not combine two apps into one APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431161/installing-two-apps-using-one-apk)
3. If you can find such a converter then this appears to be your only feasible course of action

Comment: Thank you CyanAngel! When you say provoke Air from Java, is that means I still need to have two standalone projects? I will dig into making Air into .jar but I may lose Air environment after doing so..

Comment: Yes you would still need two separate projects. Best you could do is tell your AIR to start. See [InvokeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html)